# Why did chown mess up my sudo.conf?

Tags: arch-linux, sudo, chown

My machine has 2 NVMe drives.

During install, I loaded everything onto one of them and left the 2nd one untouched. I figured this would be a good way to learn about mounting drives after install. So I mounted it to `/mnt/Second`.

I tried moving files to it and learned what most of you probably already know: mounting a drive doesn't give the current user permissions for it.
So, with `/mnt` as my current directory, I did:

```
sudo chown -R myusername Second
```

cool, I was able to move files to it.

**But** now when I try to use `sudo`, I get:

```
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

Questions:

Why did changing the owner of `/mnt/Second` change the ownership of `/etc/sudo.conf` and `/usr/bin/sudo`?

Is my system completely borked now or can this be fixed ?

Comment: If that was the actual `chown` command that you used, then it should not have affected the ownerships of the `sudo`-related files. If you look at these files with `ls -l`, what are their ownerships? What about other files under `/etc` and `/usr/bin` and other directories?

Answer (score 0):

No idea how that command changed the permissions of a file in a different path.

To fix, start up your host from a [bootable USB drive](https://www.techradar.com/best/best-linux-repair-and-rescue-distros), mount the drive change change the onership back to root.

If /etc/sudo.conf got changed there will probably be other file access broken by this. If you don't have backups (shame on you) then it may be simpler to backup /home (along with any other data directories) now and reinstall.